# Need to ensure C# HDF5 output (of attributes) is same as Visual C++. Or what is equivalent HDF5 formatting in C# as C++

Tags: c#, visual-c++, hdf5

I wrote another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812721/hdf5-c-sharp-examples-to-solve-3-specific-questions-i-demonstrate-what-has-been) that was flagged as too general, so I'm rewriting to be clearer, more succinct, and as specific as possible.  I have used Visual C++ and HDF5 (see: www.hdfgroup.org) to output some datasets.  All works well.  To format two of the attributes in C++, I use

```
DataSpace attr_dataspace = DataSpace(H5S_SCALAR);  
Attribute attribute_cardNum = dataSet.createAttribute(
    attrCardNumber, PredType::STD_I32BE, attr_dataspace, PropList::DEFAULT);
attribute_cardNum.write(PredType::NATIVE_INT, &cardNumber);  // write out the card number
```

and

```
StrType strdatatype(PredType::C_S1, 256); // of length 256 characters
// Create attribute and write to it
Attribute attribute_boardName = dataSet.createAttribute(
    attrBoardName, strdatatype, attr_dataspace);
attribute_boardName.write(strdatatype, asciiBoardName);
```

Using the HDF5 Java viewer for example, I get

```
Name        Value       Type        Array Size

Board Name  UltraMaster String,length=256   Scalar
Card number     0       32-bit integer      Scalar
```

When I use C# to export the HDF5 (using libraries at hdf5.net), I get:

```
 Name       Value       Type        Array Size

Board Name  ˜„      String, length=256  1
Card Number 0       32-bit integer      1
```

Note that the Array Size is now "1" instead of scalar, and the Value for Board Name is totally hosed up.
My C# code is different (obviously :)).  I have:

```
// Create card Number attribute
H5AttributeId attrCardId =   H5A.create(dataSetId, "Card Number", typeId, 
   H5S.create_simple(1, new long[1] { 1 }));
H5A.write(attrCardId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT), 
   new H5Array<int> (new int[]{cardNumber}));

// Create Board Name attribute
byte[] asciiStr = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Board Name");
H5AttributeId attrBoardNameId = H5A.create(dataSetId, "Board Name",
   H5T.create(H5T.CreateClass.STRING, 256), H5S.create_simple(1, new long[1] { 1 }));
H5A.write(attrBoardNameId, H5T.create(H5T.CreateClass.STRING,256), 
     new H5Array<string>(new string[] { GetBoardNameFromCardNum(cardNumber) }));
```

As I said, the results are different. It would be desirable to have the C# mimic the C++ output (although I suppose I could change the C++ code).  So specifically,

1. How do I get the array size to be "Scalar"
2. How to I output the board Name?  I assume this has something to do with the fact that I'm dealing with C# strings (unicode) and not C++ ascii strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone needs this at some later point, the relevant code that worked for me was:

```
// Card Number Attribute
 H5AttributeId attrCardId =   H5A.create(dataSetId, "Card Number", typeId, H5S.create(H5S.H5SClass.SCALAR));
        H5A.write(attrCardId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT), new H5Array<int> (new int[]{cardNumber}));
```

Notice the H5A.create instead of H5A.create_simple

```
 // Create Board Name attribute
        byte[] asciiStr = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetBoardNameFromCardNum(cardNumber));
        H5AttributeId attrBoardNameId = H5A.create(dataSetId, "Board Name", H5T.create(H5T.CreateClass.STRING, 256), H5S.create(H5S.H5SClass.SCALAR));
        H5A.write(attrBoardNameId, H5T.create(H5T.CreateClass.STRING,256), new H5Array<byte>(asciiStr));
```

Additionally, I'd like to point out that there are some HDF5.net examples at:
HDF5.net.  Look for •HDF5DotNet source and examples
Once you get that, look under the "tests" folder as well as the "example" folder.

Cheers,

Dave